# Cadastrar usuário com foto no firebase

Tags: android, firebase, app, realtime-database

Boa noite!
  Pessoal, estou fazendo um cadastro de usuarios no meu app e gostaria de além dos dados pessoais que salvarei no realtime database eu gostaria de salvar também a foto de perfil e uma foto de capa(ou pode ser só a foto de perfil mesmo), mas não sei como criar o usuario no database e linkar essa foto para quando eu for trazer os dados do perfil.
Vocês poderiam me orientar com algum exemplo de código ou algum link que possa me ajudar? 
Obrigado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

eu aconselharia você a usar o firebase AUTH, para autenticar seu usuário e usar a foto de perfil do facebook,ou do google+ automaticamente.Mas caso queira utilizar uma foto escolhida pelo usuário,você deve utilizar o firebase Storage,Quando for enviar a mensagem para o database,você vai enviar a imagem do usuario para o storage do firebase,e recuperar essa url no nó do seu usuário também ao mesmo tempo.Se você fizer este curso free ,você vai conseguir fazer essa operação tranquilamente:[curso firebase wekend](https://br.udacity.com/course/firebase-in-a-weekend-by-google-android--ud0352/)

O que você verá no curso:

```
 Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

//      Get a reference to store file at firebase storage/<FILENAME>

        StorageReference photoRef = mChatPhotosStorageReference.child(selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment());

//      Upload file to Firebase Storage

        photoRef.putFile(selectedImageUri)

                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

//  When the image has successfully uploaded, we get its download URL

                        Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();




// Set the download URL to the message box, so that the user can send it
// to the database

                        FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = new FriendlyMessage(TEXTO, NOME-DO-USUÁRIO, downloadUrl.toString(),DADOS-DO-USUÁRIO.............);
                        mMessagesDatabaseReference.push().setValue(friendlyMessage);

                    }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Oto! Sensacional a dica do curso e o trecho do código, me ajudou e com certeza será bem util para outras pessoas também !

Comment: Olá. Pra usar com Ionic 3 teria algum exemplo?

Comment: infelizmente não @EzequielTavares ,não utilizo esta plataforma de desenvolvimento.